# Can't preseed the installer

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I grabbed the Ubuntu 16.04 Live image from ubuntu.com and it works fine, both in live mode and in the installer, but I need to preseed the installer.

I can modify everything in the initrd and it works fine, but as soon as I add the preseed.cfg file to its root it stops working.

When I select "Install" in the Live USB boot menu it throws me some errors related to Invalid Arguments when trying to unmount some partitions. The installation goes on, but in the partitioning screen no partition is displayed, and I can't finish the installation.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try putting the cfg file into the preseed directory?  How are you modifying and recreating the ISO?  Note that FAT fs do not allow links, so the "ubuntu" link to . does not work, and the /cdrom/preseed... cannot be set up.

Comment: First, I extracted the ISO's content to a local directory by mounting it and copying the files. Then I extracted and rebuilt the initrd with gzip and cpio. I used GNU Xorriso to rebuild the ISO. I used dd to write the ISO to a flash drive, so I don't think it has a filesystem at all.

Comment: You can add such info to the original question.  Seems good, the file copy from the ISO was to an ext? fs so there was no error on the "ubuntu" link copy?  You can mount the flash using the -tiso9660 filesystem type ( on /dev/sdc1 for example and with -oro too)  and take a look at what was produced.  Also compare the ISO created with the original.

Comment: Which media are you using? (Desktop, Server, Netboot, ...)